# x:name is not working for codebhind in xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, code-behind

I'm working on an app and when i use x:name in a entry to access the input string in code behind then its not working working code behind is not accessing the x name

XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="LogIN.HomePage">
    <Content Page. Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label x:Name="Bilal"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Did you try building the application before trying to access it in the code behind

Comment: Not directly related, but I would highly recommend using the MVVM pattern to write Xamarin applications rather than code behind.

Comment: After setting in xaml , save and build  first.